# undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this.refs.toast.show')

Tags: react-native

My aim is to listen the event for Android homeback button, and then give a toast when continuous click. Here the third component "react-native-easy-toast" is used, fully code snippets shown as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {View, WebView, Platform, BackHandler, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import Toast, {DURATION} from 'react-native-easy-toast';

export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
    constructor (props) {
      super(props);
    }

    onNavigationStateChange = (event) => {
      this.setState({
        navCanGoBack : event.canGoBack,
      });
    };

    componentDidMount() {
      if (Platform.OS === 'android') {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.onHomeBackPress);
      }
    }


    onHomeBackPress = () => {
      if (this.state.navCanGoBack) {
        this.refs['webview'].goBack();
        return true;
      } else {
        //exit app if exceed 2 seconds
        if (this.lastBackPressed && this.lastBackPressed + 2000 >= Date.now()) {
          return false;
        }
        this.lastBackPressed = Date.now();
        this.refs.toast.show('weill exit app press again');
        return true;
      }
    };

    render() {
      return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            <WebView
              source={{ uri: 'http://www.test.com/' }}
              style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
              ref="webview"
              onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
            />

            <Toast ref="toast" />
        </View>
      );
    }
}
```

Finally, run the app and error given:

> undefined is not an object(evaluating '_this.refs.toast.show')

I am newer to React Native.

Comment: As per `this.refs['webview'].goBack();` should be `this.refs['toast'].show('weill exit app press again');`

Comment: tks a lot, after change to this.refs['toast'].show('will exit app press again'); the same error still exist.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
//inside constructor
this.toastRef = React.createRef();

...

<Toast ref={this.toastRef} />
```

and replace

`this.refs.toast.show('weill exit app press again');`

to

`this.toastRef.current.show('weill exit app press again');`